# How to dissolve slime jelly?

Tags: everyday-chemistry, water

Suppose I have a small kid that had two cans of slime jelly (a Jelly made of water, glycerin, thickeners, dispersant, flavorings and pigments).

And that two cans were inside a backpack, and somehow opened and spread in the bottom. Involving some dolls, small toy cars, entrancing in some holes. Even after trying physical processes not all jelly could be removed.

Adding water and soap did not difference, as jelly is still there, and even the two colors haven't mixed.

How can I dissolve those jelly, preferably leaving the nylon backpack, the metal cars and the plastic dolls without significant damage?

Comment: I like the surreptitious  *"Suppose I have a small kid that had two cans of slime jelly..."* :D

Comment: I'd put everything (perhaps not the toy cars) in the washing machine, use a long program without heating, and let nature take it's course. No detergents, just water and mechanical agitation.

Comment: @paracetamol oh, I would end my question stating that "bonus points" would be making that kid happy again with her backpack. But I don't have enough reputation to offer a bounty... so I forgot to end it that way.

Comment: It may help to have the particular brand of slime jelly. The thing that's causing you the issue is the thickener/polymer being used, not the water/glycerin/pigments. Knowing the exact chemical makeup of the polymer doing the gelling would assist greatly in figuring out how to get rid of it. -- I suggest mentioning the brand, because that's our only lead into the identity of the polymer, if it's not listed explicitly on the container.

Comment: @R.M. It's a small brand from Brazil, manufactured by Asca Toys (www.ascatoys.com). It's called "Amoeba". There's no information in the package/site besides that the patent involves cellulose. Now I'm trying with some bleaching product, those that don't use chlorine.